# GAE Data Models for Events and shared Resources

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, scalability

I'm having trouble coming up with good data models and queries that scale well for modeling data similar to Google Calendar's Events and Resources.

Resources are shared among users and a Resource can only be in one Event at a time. A Resource will have multiple events, but those Events cannot overlap or be happening at the same time. An Event can also have multiple resources.

```
class event(db.Model):
  #user that created/owns the event
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(user, collection_name='events',required=True)

  #an event can have multiple resources
  resources = db.StringListProperty() # resource key(s)

  #when the event opens and closes (start/stop)
  opendt = db.DateTimeProperty()
  closedt = db.DateTimeProperty()

class resource(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

With these data models, I have not been able to come up with a quick, scalable way to get the list of available resources when creating an event.

1. Get all Resources (simple query)
2. Get all events that overlap the new event (multiple queries)

   1. find events that start before and end after the new event
   2. find events that start before and end during the new event
   3. find events that start and end during the new event
   4. find events that start during and end after the new event
3. Filter out the resources that are included in the overlapping events

I feel like this process would get slower and slower as more events and resources are added.  I also don't know how this would work to be able to paginate the end result of resources.

When a user is creating a new event, after they enter the start/stop datetimes of their new event, I would like them to quickly be able to see the available resources for that time frame.

Is there a better, more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, will this work:
1.  Use a long integer to represent your chunks of time, kinda like the Unix timer, but use large chunks of time, so say each increment represents 15 minutes.  ie 0 = 1/1/2012 00:00, 1 = 1/1/2012 00:15, 2 = 1/1/2012 00:30, etc.

In both your resources, and event, store a ListProperty of long integers for all the time quanta that they are occupied.

If you want to see if a resource or event is "active" at a certain point in time, just calculate the long integer value for that time chunk, and search for it in the ListProperty using the "in" filter in your query.

Comment: if a resource is reserved for one hour (0123), and a new event is 00:15-00:45 (12), how would that query work? "12" is not IN ["0123"]

Comment: Store it in a list instead of a string.  So a resource is reserved for one hour [0, 1, 2, 3].  If you wanted to search for one particular time, I'm certain that 1 is IN [0, 1, 2, 3].

I believe you can query for [1, 2] IN [0, 1, 2, 3] and it should return what you expect.  I haven't tried this myself, but according to the description of the IN operation in the Overview section here, it sounds right:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Properties_With_Multiple_Values_Can_Have_Surprising_Behaviors

Comment: i was thinking they would be strings so i could store multiple reservations ["0123","789"], but with your example i would just add another reservation to the list [0,1,2,3,7,8,9]

Comment: the end result needs to be resources that are available for the specified time, not resources that are reserved for that time, so i would really need to do a NOT IN, but that doesnt seem to exist. also, IN queries execute multiple sub queries so i dont think this would be saving much over date comparisons, especially for long events. even if the increment was 24 hours, a month long event would have 30 queries, which is the max limit on sub queries.